# Aggregation field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two MongoDb collections:

**FILM**

```
{ _id: ObjectId("60644a81655e8216acf44b6e"), name: 'Django' }
{ _id: ObjectId("60647242c31ba840a0479221"), name: 'Kill Bill' }
```

**SCREENING**

```
{ _id: ObjectId("60644598655e8216acf44b6a"),
  name: 'Django',
  reviews: '1150',
  cinema: '01' }
{ _id: ObjectId("606445c7655e8216acf44b6b"),
  name: 'Django',
  reviews: '2130',
  cinema: '02' }
{ _id: ObjectId("606445c7655e8216acf44b6c"),
  name: 'Django',
  reviews: '2102',
  cinema: '03' }
{ _id: ObjectId("60647218c31ba840a047921f"),
  name: 'Kill Bill',
  reviews: '2000',
  cinema: '01' }
{ _id: ObjectId("60647218c31ba840a0479220"),
  name: 'Kill Bill',
  reviews: '587',
  cinema: '02' }
```

I want to add, in FILM collection, a new aggregation field total_reviews, that sum the total reviews of a FILM; for example:

**FILM**

```
{ _id: ObjectId("60644a81655e8216acf44b6e"), name: 'Django', total_reviews: "3382" }
{ _id: ObjectId("60647242c31ba840a0479221"), name: 'Kill Bill', total_reviews: "2587"}
```

Someone can I help me?
Thanks...

Comment: MongoDB is a Document Database and as such does not support computed fields. You can, as you already demonstrated, use the aggregation framework to receive "calculated" results as a cursor or as a new collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the on clause on merge and it works

```
db.film.aggregate([
   {$lookup: {from: "screening", localField: "_id", foreignField: "film_id", as: "screening"}},
   {$set: {total_reviews : {$sum : "$screening.review"}}},
   {$project : {id:0, screening:0}},
   { $merge: { into: { db: "test", coll: "film" }, on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
   ])
```

But if insert a new screening document, the field total_reviews is not updated automatically. There are a method (like a SQL trigger) to automate this function?

Comment: If this is a correction to the answer, edit the answer, these aren't two answers unless they are two significantly different solutions that both work and even then, they should be stated as options in a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct solution, that provides with 4 stages:

```
db.film.aggregate([
   {$lookup: {from: "screening", localField: "name", foreignField: "name", as: "screening"}},
   {$addFields: {total_reviews : {$sum : "$screening.review"}}},
   {$project : {id:0, screening:0}},
   {$merge: {into: {db: "test", coll: "film"}, on: "_id",
            whenMatched: "replace",whenNotMatched: "insert"}}
   ])
```

And this is a result:

```
[{ name: 'Django', total_reviews: 5382 }, 
{ name: 'Kill Bill', total_reviews: 2587 }]
```